# Combine names + types into a typed list in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have two types that I need to combine:

```
// dynamic type:
class MyEvent<T> {
}
```

and

```
// list of event names with types:
interface IEvents {
    receive: string;
    data: any[];
    count: number;
}
```

How can we combine those types automatically into the following type? -

```
type Combined = {
    receive: MyEvent<string>,
    data: MyEvent<any[]>,
    count: MyEvent<number>
}
```

Is there any standard way of doing it within TypeScript?

I've checked all the [standard utilities](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), but apart from `Record`, nothing comes close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) for this:

```
type Combined = {
  [P in keyof IEvents]: MyEvent<IEvents[P]>;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=3&pln=10&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBRAbgUwHYBcA8AVAfNAN4CwAUAL7nkCWWqATgGZjCrQCSKGmMpZ0QdAao2NNAC5oETAzoBzANzkh0ACZhMYKWHTwA2gF1lAocAD2AVyxT0lgLYAjRiaplymeAAd2AYXNOdKhq0AC8xCrQ%20gAK0HTQANao8OZMnNxYEIZSCBk4XGiZMYb4ropAA)

Comment: Such type only controls the property names, but it does not control their value types at all, which means they can be set to anything, and that's no good. So part `[P in keyof IEvents]` works, but `MyEvent<IEvents[P]>` doesn't, for some reasons.

Comment: It does work. Did you check the playground? Can you post a link to an example in the playground not working?

Comment: Sure, [here's the link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBRAbgUwHYBcA8AVAfNAN4CwAUAL7nkCWWqATgGZjCrQCSKGmMpZ0QdAao2NNAC5oETAzoBzANzkh0ACZhMYKWHTwA2gF1lAocAD2AVyxT0lgLYAjRiaplymeAAd2AYXNOdKhq0AC8xCrQ+gAK0HTQANao8OZMnNxYEIZSCBk4XGiZMYb4ribkFugy0ABiYDQgwbioMlL+gejBYRGmImKS0ACMAEwAzAA00AD0AFRx6MhgIDQhnj7QSyDmAO7Bk-aW1RhM5gxscEiFODJy6PKEM1ORGlpSAER0i8ur3qhvk7N5l8VtA1uxNjs9tADkd0CczuxcldsLoDCVoI9IhZrJgpAAWACsADZpnNPksQWCNiAtrs1PtDphoMdTuckTxsHYnIwHk9KCYgA). You can see there, it fails to control the type, treating each type as `any`.

Comment: If you hover over the `Combined` type you will see that the type is correct. The reason that your example doesn't error is that your class is empty and you're running into the fact that the type system is structural. For example, `const x: MyEvent<number> = 42;` also compiles.

Comment: For reference, see here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#classes

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks! So I had to add actual type `T` usage inside `MyEvent` to see the type controlled properly. Now it works as expected.